# Как перехватить ошибку/исключение в javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Использую библиотеку [socket.io-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis)

Пример:

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import redisAdapter from 'socket.io-redis';

const io = new Server(3000);
io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

**И вот тут проблема:**

Если что-то будет с `redis` - **приложение падает**. Если неверный пароль - **приложение падает**.

Смотрел через `Object.prototype.toString.call`: `io` - объект, экземпляр класса. `redisAdapter` - метод, `io.adapter` - метод. Обычные методы, не асинхронные.

Пробовал завернуть весь код в `try, catch` - не помогло. Пробовал в объект, что передаем в `redisAdapter`, передать `retry_strategy`. С `redis` работает, тут - нет.

Есть идея подписаться как: `.on("event", callback)`. Но нет идей, на что его поставить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
io.of('/').adapter.on('error', function(){});
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis#client-error-handling).

Comment: Забавно, пытался так: `io.adapter.on("error", () => console.log("test"))` - не работает.